# SQL Server - Subquery in joins vs not

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, query

My application has huge recordset in various tables (> 1 billion records) and wondering the better approach as I have read multiple contradictory articles. Question is what is better in performance (inner joins)

1. Join the table and then filter in where clause
2. Join with subquery that filters records

Example

```
Select T1.Id 
from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2 on T1.JoinId = T2.T1JoinId
where T1.RefId = 1
```

VS

```
Select T1.Id 
from (select Id,T1JoinId from Table1 where RefId = 1) T1
inner join Table2 T2 on T1.JoinId = T2.T1JoinId
```

My understanding is that execution plan would be made quicker in second case but performance wise, it would be same as actual plan would be same

Comment: It might depend on your own particular environment - have you done any benchmarks, obtained  any plans?

Answer (score 3):

You're basically asking, "What's the fastest way to join two tables?"

The answer is going to depend on a lot of things, even coming down to how much time SQL Server has to spend when optimizing the query.

Your best bet, rather than asking a general theoretical question, would be to run the query both ways and compare:

- The output from SET STATISTICS IO ON, which puts the number of reads done from each table in the Messages tab of SSMS
- The output from SET STATISTICS TIME ON, which puts the amount of CPU time & overall duration in the Messages tab too (but be aware that this can vary a lot between passes, depending on what other activity is happening on your server at the time)
- The actual (not estimated) execution plan, which can have additional details like which plan spilled to disk or ran into plan optimization timeouts

Comment: I read in one SQL book that sequence of execution is based on the query written and "where" clause is applied on the resultset fetched post join - which basically means that join is done on the full table instead of filtered records. I do not know if that is true but if that is true, then I was assuming that join to subquery  would result in better performance but I did not see any difference. I am not a DBA so wanted to understand what should the standard be (excluding 1% cases where performance is degraded)

Comment: @Ankit that is not correct, no.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with Brent, just like to add a couple of thoughts:

The optimizer has a bunch of transformation rules. I.e., one way to formulate something can be transformed into a different way. Very early in the optimization phase, such rules are applied.

You shouldn't assume that the plan resembles the "order" of things in your query, including subqueries. In other words, in most cases, you will find your two queries generating the same plan.

Does the same plan means identical performance? Yes, to a large degree. Until you have a noticeable compile time compared to execution time *and* one of your queries has a significant smaller compile time. I have a feeling that if you do due diligence for every query you write, you will get tired from seeing none (or possibly  only a minuscule) performance difference before you hit the odd case where there is a noticeable difference.